# React image slider with dynamic data, first Image coming after clickEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a grid of images coming from an API, and now I am trying to build a slider.
First image to be displayed should be the one clicked in the Grid below the slider , and when clicked next/prev go to the nex/prev img in the array.

How could I get it?

I am trying by setting the initial state of ``ìmgToShow```to the img clicked, but i get nothing in console. The idea would be to get that, and then , i still dont know how, update the state to show the next img in the Array.

`album` is the array of objects with all the images. Fetched in my Context component
`clickedImage`contains the clicked image's URL. I get it from a click event in other component.

This is my component :

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { AlbumContext } from "../../context/AlbumContext";
import "./carousel.css";
import BtnSlider from "./BtnSlider";

function Carousel() {
  const { clickedImage, albums } = useContext(AlbumContext);

  const [imgToShow, setImgToShow] = useState(clickedImage);
    console.log("imgTOSHOW", imgToShow); // empty in console
    console.log("clickedIMG in context", clickedImage); // gives me the URL clicked

  
  const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(1);

  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (slideIndex !== albums.length) {
      setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1);
    } else if (slideIndex === albums.length) {
      setSlideIndex(1);
    }
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="container-slider">
      {albums &&
        albums.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={item.id}
              className={
                slideIndex === index + 1 ? "slide active-anim" : "slide"
              }
            >
              
              <img src={imgToShow} alt="" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      <BtnSlider moveSlide={nextSlide} direction={"next"} />
      <BtnSlider moveSlide={prevSlide} direction={"prev"} />
    </div>

  );
}

export default Carousel
```

Comment: beside ```src={imgToShow}``` you can simply write ```src={albums.imagePath[slideIndex]}``` just get the image from the original array by the slide index. if it makes sense..

Comment: 1st of all , thanks.
That would work to slide through the array, regardless of the image I click below ...but I don't see how to make the starting image in the slider, the image I click  ```clickedImage```

Comment: On clicking on the image you need to set the slider index ```setSlideIndex``` to the image index, therefor you need to store the index (if you are mapping its easy) in the div / img id or any other attribure, it can look like this: ```onClick={(e)=>{setSlideIndex(e.target.id)}}``` with the comment above and this comment it should work. if you need better explaination let me know i will write a full answer.

Comment: I will try this right know. 
Could I ask something more?
How could I set the URL , so I if I would share the URL with a different user, after pasting it, he could see that image and continue the slider from there?

Comment: This is a bit more complicated, what i would do is to write the image index as param, for example: ```www.url.com/page?img=5``` then in the component to do useEffect that will check if there is param (with location.query you can achieve it). if exist then you can ```setSlideIndex(parseInt(location.query.img))``` but in this case you need every change event (click on image, prev, next) to set the param.

Comment: Thanks!
Although i need to figure a few things before, it sounds like a good way. 
Tomorrow I'll try.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: hey @Elnatanvazana , follwing your suggestion, i  did
  ```{albums.imagePath[slideIndex]}``` and set ```slideIndex```with the ```id ``` after I click on an Img .
The problem now is at the first render. Since there is no click, the value of ``slideIndex```is undefined and throws me an error.

Comment: What you can do is to set the first image as default ```useState(0)``` or you can check if slideIndex is defined and then to show the image ```{slideIndex && <img src... />}``` so in this case you need to leave the useState empty or null.. you can display something else beside image as default if you want ```{slideIndex ? <img... /> : <div>...</div>}```